# Custom Code to repeat static row on a new group instance only

Tags: vba, reporting-services, report

I have a report where the end user has an input section strictly for in person use.  It is a row where they choose "yes" or "no", basically.  The issue is that this section is based per group.  So, for example, each group is a sales order, that order may have many pages, this "yes/no" section requirement is to only show on the first page of each group.

Note, I have tried to used the Previous function to hide the row, using a field a field from the header section, no luck there. I'm not a programmer by trade and more over don't have experience in VBA

I have exhausted my searches on Google and it doesn't seem like anyone has done this before. It may not be possible because in the row the fields are static texts and aren't referenced from a real dataset.

Appreciate any input or work around that could work, or solidify the fact this isn't possible in SSRS

Comment: isn't this a bit like adding the words "cont.." on the next page if the grouping is split over multiple pages? something like this perhaps: - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/chrishays/continued-header-on-subsequent-pages

Comment: @Harry No, Because it isn't something to be repeated on each page of the group, only shows on the first instance of it.  The sale order may have many pages per item it runs through.  However, it only gives the row on the first page of each item

Comment: just an idea, haven't tried it out.. how about you create a row_number for each group in your dataset..  but only show the value "Yes /No" when the row_number = 1 and then display that as part of the group..